# Is it possible to wait for a thread in Rust inside main without taking ownership of its content?

Tags: rust

I'm rendering an image line by line and want to render a certain amount of them at the same time.
Using join would take ownership of the underlying Vec. Is there a more elegant solution than

```
while !thread.is_finished() {
     let mut child = Command::new("sleep").arg("1").spawn().unwrap();
     child.wait().unwrap();
}
```

without the need to change the JoinHandle return type to something copyable?

Without implementing waiting up to 2400 threads get spawned simultaneously which is bad.
When trying to use join the compiler returns `` error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*thread` which is behind a shared reference ``.

Edit:

1. I'm rendering the image line by line, rendering each line inside a thread, storing those threads inside a vec.
2. I know its bad. I didn't know how to implement it better.
3. Thanks, that works, I'd upvote but don't have the necessary points for that.

Comment: This needs more context: How is rendering an image related to threading, vectors, or calling a command? Are you really using the sleep command, or is a stand-in for something else? (there's a built-in [`sleep`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) function).

Comment: PSA: Stay *away* from running external commands to do basic things like add a delay, wait for input, etc. This is a really bad anti-pattern. If you're using this as a stand-in for more complicated operations, a little more explanation can help focus any answer.

Comment: You can store an `Option<JoinHandle>` and `.take().unwrap().join()` it.

Comment: Can you provide full code that fails to compile and demonstrates the issue?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Chunks.html shows, you can partition the vector into chunks - using this, you could control the number of threads working in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use crossbeam scoped threads. Scoped threads can spawn a thread that borrows data from the parent thread. The borrow checker will guarantee that the child thread will finish before the parent thread exists.

This allows you to avoid the ownership issues that arise when using join();

```
use crossbeam::scope;

let lines_per_batch = 100;

for batch_start in (0..total_lines).step_by(lines_per_batch) {
    scope(|s| {
        let batch_end = batch_start + lines_per_batch;
        let lines = &image_lines[batch_start..batch_end];
        s.spawn(|_| {
            for line in lines {
                // Render the image line
            }
        });
    });
}
```

We are using `crossbeam::scope` to create a new thread scope. Inside the scope, we are creating a new slice of lines to render the current batch. We are then spawning a new thread that will render each line in that batch. We are borrowing the `image_lines` slice from the parent thread and Rusts borrow checker will ensure that the child will finish before the parent thread exists.

Comment: Well I think I did answer his question for another solution to render an image line by line threaded. As the scope of the question did not clarify more requirements that crossbeam::scope should suffice.

Comment: Please [avoid answering unclear questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315370/a-good-strategy-for-unclear-questions). Guessing at the intent is more than likely to be wrong and would lead to unhelpful answers. Use the comments to engage with the OP to clarify their goal before providing a concrete resolution.

Comment: @kmdreko afaik the question was quite clear and asked for more elegant solution to render image line by line threaded, so that he would not lose ownership of the vec to threads. I did not touch the rendering code as he did not clarify that in the question, just the threading part. So in that case my answer should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see your problem, is that you have some sort of Provider/Consumer pattern of concurrency. Some "Provider" computes stuff, some "Consumer" wants to render stuff, using partial results.

This kind of pattern is not well supported by APIs, focusing on "parallel computation".

While I am not going to give you a workable solution in code, here an outline:

Provider(s) are running in parallel threads, are being tasked to compute a partial solution of the full problem (the whole image). There is a limited amount of worker threads, used by the providers (This hints to a thread pool). And they use "work stealing", tackling the next partial problem, once done with a previous one.
Whenever a partial computation is done, the provider sends an event (message) about the finished "range", so the consumer can receive the event and go at rendering that section.

- Thread Pool (maybe number of cores on machine or a few more or less)
- Work list, filled in by application prior to kicking off computation
- Providers draw from work list, compute, signal results (Results Queue).
- (Single) Consumer thread blocks on Results Queue until there is a result, then renders and rinse repeat.

I am optimistic, that there is already a package in the rust ecosystem, which supports this kind of workflow.